# Bit shift issue

Tags: java

Given the Following code:

```
public class Something {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 1;

    num <<= 32;
    System.out.println(num); 

    num = 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 32; i++)
        num <<= 1;
    System.out.println(num);
}
}
```

The first output (from num <<= 32) is 1.

and the second output (from the for loop) is 0.

I dont get it.. it looks the same to me.. 
both ways shift the "1" digit (lsb) 32 times and the results are different.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone explain?

Absolutely. Basically, shift operations on `int` have the right operand masked to get a value in the range [0, 31]. Shift operations on `long` have it masked to get a value in the range [0, 63].

So:

```
num <<= 32;
```

is equivalent to:

```
num <<= 0;
```

From [section 15.19 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

Comment: See [JLS 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For bit shift operators on `int`, only the [5 lowest order bits are used](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-do-the-bitwise-shift-operators-work/12).  So `<< 32` does nothing; it's equivalent to `<< 0`, because the last 5 bits of 32 are 0.  But the `<< 1` operations in the loop each perform as expected.